# loading a jar with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, jar

I am testing a c++ code developed under Linux. I am using Visual Studio because I can only work with windows. Until here this is ok, I can compile. Anyway I still have a problem when loading a jar (used for JNI). I have this error in the debugger :

```
0xcccccccc - Unable to read Memory
```

Here is the piece of code :

```
const char * JAR_LIBRARY_PATH="./myJar.jar";
```

Comment: The fact that you have to use Windows doesn't mean you have to use VS.

Comment: @X.L.Ant But it wouldn't smart to not use microsoft's best product.

Comment: Hey guys do you have any solution ? Just to be sure, because this problem makes me mad, a jar doesn't depend of the platform it was compiled on ? I'm sure the problem comes from somewhere else.